# Can't read from file all integers of a line (ifstream)

Tags: c++, ifstream

This function is supposed to open a .txt file like this:

```
1    4    5 

2    4    6
```

etc. (with tab between numbers)

and save each number in one variable

```
void Graph::readData(char* fname)
{
    //cout<<"1";
    int x,y,w;//assistant variables
    ifstream input;//stream for reading file
    input.open(fname,ios::in);
    if(!input)
    {
        cerr<<"Input file doesn't exist"<<endl;//error if file doens exist
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Input file opened"<<endl;
        cout<<"Reading Data from file..."<<endl;
        while(!input.eof())//till the end of file
        {
            input>>x>>y>>w;//reads the links-site
            cout<<"x: "<<x<<"y:"<<y<<"w: "<<w<<endl;
            insertLink(x,y,w);//inserts them

        }
        input.close();//closing file
    }
}
```

However, when I "cout" the results I get something like this:

```
x=1  y=  w=5

x=2  y=  w=6
```

without y!

Why could this happen?

PS: In addition, eof() becomes true after the file is finished (reads one extra line). How can I stop while iteration properly?

This is the file I'm trying to read from: http://www.speedyshare.com/tpvuD/input.txt

Comment: Regarding your PS: [Why is `iostream::eof` inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Apart from `eof` check, the code should work, which means that the error is in the code you're not showing us or that input file isn't in the format you said it is.

Comment: "...when I 'cout' the results..." those results aren't from the output loop in this posted code. For starters, the posted code has colons (`:`), not equals (`=`). Whatever you're claiming is improper output, it isn't from that loop. My crystal ball tells me the code that *is* writing your output never sends the y-value to the output stream, but without seeing the *real* code, its impossible to say for sure. [That loop works](http://ideone.com/UXZ6I9) once you fix the erroneous while-condition.

Comment: "=" was my... " mistake...
http://s12.postimg.org/591imz659/Screenshot_35.png

These are the results I get!

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "c++ read file integer parse"

Answer (score 1):

To stop the iteration properly, write the loop as:

```
while(input>>x>>y>>w)//till the end of file
{ /* ... */ }
```

Do not check `input.eof()`.

Comment: And what if I have something like this: 

while(!file.eof()) {

if(...){
input>>x;
}

else {
input>>x>>y>>w;
}
}

Comment: Then, `while(input>>x) { if(...) { ... } else { input>>y>>w; ... }`